# Is there a way to express the following SQL query using Sequelize model methods?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've been trying all afternoon to express the following SQL query using a Sequelize model method such as findOne() -

```
SELECT * FROM "Tariffs" WHERE "tariffType" = 'DateRange' AND (('${body.startDate}' BETWEEN "startDate" AND "endDate") OR ('${body.endDate}' BETWEEN "startDate" AND "endDate")) LIMIT 1
```

where `body.startDate` and `body.endDate` are provided by an HTTP post - `startDate` and `endDate` are date columns held in a PostgreSQL backend.

Obviously I can execute this directly using `query()` but this defeats the purpose of using an ORM in the first place.

A standard where object provided to `findOne()` doesn't seem to provide an obvious way to supply a literal value to match against and always expects column names and *then* a value. There is a `sequelize.where()` method however which does allow you to get around this to some degree, and the best I've been able to come up with is this monstrosity -

```
Tariffs.findOne({
    where: {
        [Op.and]: [{
                tariffType: "DateRange"
            },
            {
                [Op.or]: [sequelize.where(sequelize.literal(`'${body.startDate}'`), Op.between, sequelize.literal('"startDate" AND "endDate"')),
                    sequelize.where(sequelize.literal(`'${body.endDate}'`), Op.between, sequelize.literal('"startDate" AND "endDate"'))
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

This makes heavy use of `sequelize.literal` which is probably also undesirable - I tried `sequelize.col` to define column names in the `where()` call but the method doesn't seem to want to interpret them as column names.

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this, or am I just going to have to stick with running a raw query?

**Edit 13/05/20**

Anatoly's answer is the correct one - thanks.

However, my original logic was wrong - I actually wanted to match records with a start and end date within the supplied start and end date as well as those with a the supplied start date within their range or the supplied end date within their range. Accordingly, an extra object was required after the `[Op.or]` operator -

```
[Op.or]: [{    
    startDate: {
        [Op.lte]: body.startDate
    },
    endDate: {
        [Op.gte]: body.startDate
    } }, {  
    startDate: {
        [Op.lte]: body.endDate
    },
    endDate: {
        [Op.gte]: body.endDate
    } }, { 
    startDate: {
        [Op.gte]: body.startDate
    },
    endDate: {
        [Op.lte]: body.endDate
    } 
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
[Op.or]: [{
  startDate: {
   [Op.lte]: body.startDate
  },
  endDate: {
   [Op.gte]: body.startDate
  }
}, {
  startDate: {
   [Op.lte]: body.endDate
  },
  endDate: {
   [Op.gte]: body.endDate
  }
}]
```